# How to send email via Django?

Tags: python, django, smtp, django-settings, django-email

In my `settings.py`, I have the following:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

# Host for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

My email code:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World', to=['user@gmail.com'])
email.send()
```

Of course, if I setup a debugging server via `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`, I can see the email in my terminal.

However, how do I actually send the email not to the debugging server but to user@gmail.com?

After reading your answers, let me get something straight:

1. Can't you use localhost(simple ubuntu pc) to send e-mails?
2. I thought in django 1.3 `send_mail()` is somewhat deprecated and `EmailMessage.send()` is used instead?

Comment: 1. You can use localhost *if you have a SMTP server running there*. 2. The exact mechanism is unimportant. The important part is that you have a SMTP server.

Comment: so if I install postfix, I can send/receive emails? How do you set up postfix to do this?

Comment: That question is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23402208/2351696

Comment: Yet SEO takes us to this page, Ignacio.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhzasigpf3Q) explains very nicely all the steps needed.

Comment: Don't think that using a third party service is the **correct** answer. It is not. You can install a MTA like `sendmail` which will allow you to send email locally.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Send the email to a real SMTP server. If you don't want to set up your own then you can find companies that will run one for you, such as Google themselves.

Comment: Awesome, I just myself an email! The above article mentioned by miku was perfect. Note the small typo correction in the comments of the article. (And I just used my regular computer/localhost. I had not set anything else up before hand.)

Comment: Which article? Could you link it again?

Answer (score 184):

I use Gmail as my SMTP server for Django. Much easier than dealing with postfix or whatever other server. I'm not in the business of managing email servers.

In settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'me@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

**NOTE**: In 2016 Gmail is not allowing this anymore by default. You can either use an external service like Sendgrid, or you can follow this tutorial from Google to reduce security but allow this option: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: is there an alternative to leaving your password as a plaintext?

Comment: You could use an email service like Mandrill that will let you use a passphrase instead, although I'm not sure that's any more helpful for you. You could also use an encryption key that's installed on your server, and make the line something like EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = my_decrypt('abi304hubaushl9rchy2y9fd29')

Comment: put it in an environment variable.  Then, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['MY_PASSWORD_THAT_YOU_CANT_KNOW']

Comment: I used the your code verbatim. My gmail account has been blocked after a few days.  My server probably sent less than 20 emails per day.  Had anyone had a similar issue with google?

Comment: On a new account, maybe. You could also try using a service like Mandrill. It's basically the same, if you follow their SMTP instructions.

Comment: SMTPAuthenticationError and I get an email "**Sign-in attempt prevented ... from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards**".  Looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdOwJ.png). Workaround by "[turning on access for less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)".  And that [worked](http://i.imgur.com/YoaUCSG.png).

Comment: Limited FROM address (3rd parameter to `send_mail()`. It can only be an email associated with your gmail account.

Comment: Is there any alternative to Sendgrid. Please suggest as I'm using subdomain of pythonanywhere.com.

Comment: Is there a statement from Google saying that SMTP is disabled for personal/free accounts? This answer says Gmail is no longer allowing SMTP in 2016, but I can confirm the SMTP works just fine with Google Apps for Business if you enable it in the Gmail App settings and use an app token for the password of the user you want to send from.

Answer (score 55):

1. Create a project: `django-admin.py startproject gmail`
2. Edit settings.py with code below:

   ```
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'email_password'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   ```
3. Run interactive mode: `python manage.py shell`
4. Import the EmailMessage module:

   ```
   from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
   ```
5. Send the email:

   ```
   email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['your@email.com'])
   email.send()
   ```

For more informations, check [`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#send-mail) and [`EmailMessage`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class) features in [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/).

**UPDATE for Gmail**

Also if you have problems sending email via gmail remember to check [this guides](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636656345878819046-1400238651&rd=1#cantsignin) from google.

In your Google account settings, go to  `Security > Account permissions > Access for less secure apps` and enable this option.

Also [create an App specific password for your gmail](https://www.lifewire.com/get-a-password-to-access-gmail-by-pop-imap-2-1171882) after you've [turned on *2-step-verification*](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?authuser=2) for it.

Then you should use *app specific password* in settings. So change the following line:

```
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your_email_app_specific_password'
```

Also if you're interested to send HTML email, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494247/2263683).

Comment: I follow your steps, I can not send, the to email do not  receive email/

Comment: what will be  **EMAIL_HOST**  for **outlookoffice365** ?

Answer (score 18):

My site is hosted on `Godaddy` and I have a private email registered on the same.
These are the settings which worked for me:

In settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abcdef'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'abc@domain.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'abc@domain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

In shell:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['def@domain.com'])
email.send()
```

Then I got "1" as the O/P i.e. Success. And I received the mail too. :)

- What is the meaning of domain.com?

Comment: Thanks, that's the easiest way for old projects < Django 1.4

Answer (score 18):

For Django version 1.7, if above solutions dont work then try the following

in **settings.py** add

```
#For email
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sender@gmail.com'

#Must generate specific password for your app in [gmail settings][1]
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app_specific_password'

EMAIL_PORT = 587

#This did the trick
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

The last line did the trick for django 1.7

Comment: This one didn't work for me for some reason. I kept getting back an error with the password being wrong. Which is strange because i got the credentials direct from Mailgun.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use **smtp as backend** in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

If you use backend as console, you will receive output in console

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

And also below settings in addition

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'urusername@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

If you are using **gmail** for this, setup **2-step verification** and **Application specific password** and copy and paste that password in above EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD value.

Answer (score 5):

I found using SendGrid to be the easiest way to set up sending email with Django. Here's how it works:

1. [Create a SendGrid account](https://app.sendgrid.com/signup) (and verify your email)
2. Add the following to your `settings.py`:

   `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<your sendgrid username>'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<your sendgrid password>'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

And you're all set!

To send email:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('<Your subject>', '<Your message>', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'])
```

If you want Django to email you whenever there's a 500 internal server error, add the following to your `settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your.email@example.com'
ADMINS = [('<Your name>', 'your.email@example.com')]
```

Sending email with SendGrid is free up to 12k emails per month.

Comment: Excellent, but haven't able to get it to work using 'apikey' as username as per documentation, and SendGrid list three dozens permission configurations per apikey for a simple sendmail...

Answer (score 4):

You could use **"Test Mail Server Tool"** to test email sending on your machine or localhost. Google and Download "Test Mail Server Tool" and set it up.

Then in your settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND= 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

From shell:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('subject','message','sender email',['receipient email'],    fail_silently=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had actually done this from Django a while back. Open up a legitimate GMail account & enter the credentials here. Here's my code -

```
from email import Encoders
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart

def sendmail(to, subject, text, attach=[], mtype='html'):
    ok = True
    gmail_user = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    gmail_pwd  = settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    msg['From']    = gmail_user
    msg['To']      = to
    msg['Cc']      = 'you@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, mtype))

    for a in attach:
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload(open(attach, 'rb').read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(a))
        msg.attach(part)

    try:
        mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 687)
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.starttls()
        mailServer.ehlo()
        mailServer.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
        mailServer.sendmail(gmail_user, [to,msg['Cc']], msg.as_string())
        mailServer.close()
    except:
        ok = False
    return ok
```

Comment: There's no need to use `smtplib` directly; Django will handle that part for you.

Comment: oh is it! how would that be? Here I entirely bypass the default django `send_mail`function & use my own...

Comment: `send_mail()` is how you would do it. You still need to assemble the message yourself, but you don't have to worry about the SMTP bits.

Answer (score 2):

Late, but:

In addition to the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` fix others have mentioned, *and* allowing less-secure apps to access the account, I had to navigate to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha while signed in as the account in question to get Django to finally authenticate.

I went to that URL through a SSH tunnel to the web server to make sure the IP address was the same; I'm not totally sure if that's necessary but it can't hurt. You can do that like so: `ssh -D 8080 -fN <username>@<host>`, then set your web browser to use `localhost:8080` as a SOCKS proxy.

Answer (score 1):

For **SendGrid - Django** Specifically:

[SendGrid Django Docs here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/django.html)

Set these variables in

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sendgrid_username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'sendgrid_password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

**in views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: Documentation and set up have changed since then but the link to the documentation still works and takes you to the correct config.

Answer (score 1):

below formate worked for me

> EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
>
> EMAIL_USE_TLS = True   EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.xxxxxxx.xxx'
>
> EMAIL_PORT = 465
>
> EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'support@xxxxx.xxx'
>
> EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxx'

Comment: how come this is the useful answer and different than others

Answer (score -1):

In settings.py configure the email as following

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

In most of the cases Gmail settings is missed out. Make sure that the less secure app access is turned on. You can also check the procedure [here](https://daily-python-4all.blogspot.com/2021/10/how-to-send-email-in-django-in-web.html)

Then send email within views
from django.core.mail import send_mail

```
def send(request):
    send_mail(
        ‘Email Subject here’,
        ‘Email content’,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [‘emailto@gmail.com’],
        fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.