# django-userena views.py and user registration issues

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-1.3, django-users

[django-userena](http://django-userena.org/) does not have a views.py file. It uses instead html files, i would like to use [this views.py](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/views.py) instead of the html files, because i want to add some other features, like a file uploader. I'm having a hard time implementing apps like [django-jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload)

The second question is how to activate the user's account automatically after that he confirms his email.

Comment: Your question contains many false assumptions and is impossible to understand. Can you re-do it please ? http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @jpic I'll do some editing, sir have you used django-userena? the question is very simple: django userena does not have a views.py file, instead it uses html files, i want to use a views.py instead of html files. and the second question is how to activate and give permission to the user automatically after he signs up. I'll do some editing the question to highlight these points. Thank you for telling me to edit it sir.

Comment: "django userena does not have a views.py file, instead it uses html files" That is one of the false assumptions I was talking about as you can see in [userena.urls](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/urls.py). It makes your question impossible to understand. You should remove that part and ask the question you where thinking of **before** you got to this insane question "how to replace html with views.py".

Comment: @jpic where is the views.py then? see [the demo](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/tree/master/demo_project) sir, no views.py it uses a bunch of html files in the template folder to do the job

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first thing that i would like to do is get rid of the html files
>   and replace them with this views.py,
>   django-userena is the first app I've seen that does not have a
>   views.py

Userena has:

- urls.py that bind urls to functions in views.py
- views.py that have functions that render templates

Now, to override stuff from userena, i wrote [a blog post just for you](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app).

> Secondly, i set up the django-userena demo project but every time a
>   user signs up, i have to login to the admin area and activate his
>   account and give him permissions, I would like to do that
>   automatically, when the user confirms his email, how?

You can set [USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/settings.html#userena-activation-required)=False in settings.py

Comment: sir please tell me where the views.py is? in which folder?

Comment: i searched every folder and could not find it, i need to edit it

Comment: sir, i have a small question, if you install djangp-userena using pip, how to set `USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED=False`, I mean how to find the settings.py, where does pip store files? I'm using virtualenv

Comment: And could you answer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049789/why-django-admin-is-not-opening-correctly/10049813#comment12858769_10049813)?