# Django- [Errno 111] Connection refused when using smtp

Tags: python, django, email, smtp

I'm working on a Django app that has a feature for sending emails to users. In a test case, I have a contact form that submits form data as a part of an email using smtp through gmail. I disabled captchas as I was advised in [this video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bhzasigpf3Q) that I've been following for tutorials but when I click the submit button I get the [Errno 111] for some reason. After seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django) and [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914687/django-sending-email/23402208#23402208), I learned that I needed to be running the site on a live server (instead of just localhost) in order to be able to send an email. However, when I tried this on a server, I got the same error as before. I'm pretty sure I followed all of the correct steps, so what could be the problem?

Here is the error traceback:

```
Django Version: 1.8.6
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'artist_tracker')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/students/ceyron/bandsync/src/bandsync-repo/artist_tracker/views.py" in contact
  58.       send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently =False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in send_mail
  62.     return mail.send()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  303.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  107.                 sent = self._send(message)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in _send
  123.             self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py" in sendmail
  731.             raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)

Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused at /contact/
Exception Value: (530, '5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 j34sm10137713qkh.39 - gsmtp', u'webmaster@localhost')
```

**contact form from views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import ContactForm, SignUpForm
# Create your views here.

from django.core.mail import send_mail

def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        # for key, value in form.cleaned_data.iteritems():
        #   print key, value
        form_email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        form_message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get("full_name")
        # print form.cleaned_data
        subject = "Site contact form"
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = [from_email]
        contact_message = ''' 
        %s: %s via %s
        '''%(form_full_name, form_message, form_email)
        send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, [to_email], fail_silently = True )

    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "forms.html", context)
```

Comment: toemail = ', '.join(to_email)   and pass string to send_mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code;

```
to_email = [from_email, 'someone@gmail.com']
```

is a list and again you passing to_email argument inside list.

Change this;

```
send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, [to_email], fail_silently = True )
```

to

```
send_mail(subject, contact_message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently = True )
```

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. It seems that there is some kind of authentication error now though. I just updated the post with the new traceback log. I set fail_silently to False, so I'm not sure if that would have caused a problem.

Comment: It seems like a separate issue so I'll just ask another question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In settings file change this

```
EMAIL_HOSTS = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOSTS_USER = "bandsyncdjango@gmail.com"
```

to

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "bandsyncdjango@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve one error, but now I'm getting a type error somehow. I edited the post with the traceback log. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Can you post your views for  /contact/

Comment: I have added the answer. try that.