# gaierror while using send_mail in django behind proxy

Tags: python, django, proxy, sendmail

I was trying to send an email from my Django app using gmail. I added these email settings to `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

But it throws this name resolution error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/code.py", line 90, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Django-1.8.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
  return mail.send()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Django-1.8.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
  return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Django-1.8.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
  new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/Django-1.8.7-py3.4.egg/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
  self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 242, in __init__
  (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 321, in connect
  self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
  self.source_address)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 494, in create_connection
  for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Note: **I am working behind a proxy.**

In addition, I tried to connect to google.com through socket:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')
```

It throws:

```
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Comment: Just overcome the exactly same problem. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: I misspelled, EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gamil.com' means:'smtp.gmail.com'. That's why I was getting this error

Answer (score 1):

1. enable pop3 in gmail.com
2. create  specific password for django application
   (http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833)

Solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23402208/5178153)

Comment: I've enabled both access to less secure apps and pop. But it is not working now too. May be the case is related to **working behind proxy**.