# How to resolve Django error "gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known"?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a demo e-commerce website to learn Django with the help of a tutorial but unfortunately stuck in one place. I am now able to send the email form to submit the form.

Its throwing an error like this:

```
Internal Server Error: /contact/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/src/contact/views.py", line 18, in contact
    send_mail(subject, message,emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 62, in send_mail
    return mail.send()   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()   File "/home/jai/Desktop/tryten/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This is the piece of code that shows the changes in the setting file to send the email.

```
setting.py 

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'jaizebra@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*************'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This is the view which is I am using.

```
View.py 
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import contactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings

# Create your views here.

def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        name  = form.cleaned_data['name']
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
        subject = 'Message from MYSITE.com'
        message = '%s %s' % (comment, name)
        emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']
        emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        send_mail(subject, message,emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)

    context = locals()
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

This is the form:

```
forms.py 

from django import forms 
class contactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100, help_text='100 Characters max.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**UPDATE:**

I struggle a lot and find that this error was coming because I was working behind the proxy. When I run this code with a network without a proxy, it runs fine.

Where should I make changes in the setting to add proxy?

I have tried something like this in

```py
# lines bellow added to 'wsgi.py' :

import os
....
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://myproxy:port"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://myproxy:port"
```

but it's not working:

Comment: Looks to me that you're running this locally. Do you have an SMTP server running locally? Can you connect when you run `telnet 127.0.0.1 25`?

Comment: Mailchimp offers great email service if you dont want to get into handling configuration for one.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Its showing error    "  Trying 127.0.0.1...
   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused"

Comment: Did you check this https://gilang.chandrasa.com/blog/sending-email-in-django-with-gmail/

Comment: Oh, you don't have an email server set up. If you use Ubuntu linux, there's is a community contributed guide for setting up Postfix here if you want to locally run an email server. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Comment: OP's error logs were very clear and readable. Someone made an edit and messed up.

Comment: Also check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6915291/2850474

Comment: nothing is working in my case :(

Comment: Have you fixed it?