# Django not sending error emails - how can I debug?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 1.8. This is my base settings file:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
ADMINS = (
   ('ME', 'me@gmail.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS
```

And these are my production settings:

```
########## EMAIL CONFIGURATION
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my.error.account@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = utils.get_env_setting('GMAIL_PASS')
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[%s] ' % SITE_NAME
SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
########## END EMAIL CONFIGURATION
```

It used to send error email in production, but has stopped. I've set up a page that returns 500 errors so that I can test this further - no emails being sent when I load it.

I've tried debugging the obvious things:

- I can still log into `my.error.account@gmail.com` and it doesn't seem to have been blocked.
- I've checked my spam filter.
- I'm certain that `DEBUG` is set false.
- I believe the `GMAIL_PASS` environment variable is available to the Django user.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: First, check that mails are being sent. Set the `HOST` to `localhost`, the `PORT` to `1025`, disable `TLS` and run a dummy SMTP server using this command: `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

Comment: In case it helps anyone, it took me a while to figure out that you not only have to specify the `mail_admins` under the `handlers` key, but you **also** have to enable that handler under the `loggers` key

Answer (score 10):

- For the debugging part of the question

  @zopieux commented:

  > First, check that mails are being sent. Set:
  >
  > ```
  > EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
  > EMAIL_PORT = 1025
  > EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
  > EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
  > ```
  >
  > Then run a dummy SMTP server:
  >
  > `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`

  If this works, you can revert the changes and manually send an email as described in this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6367014/2996101):

  ```
  from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
  email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'World', to=['user@gmail.com'])
  email.send()
  ```
- For the feature of using Google as SMTP server:

  [The most popular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367458/2996101) -and updated- answer of the question states that Google does not support anymore this  feature (2016) and that you should try to find another SMTP server.

I have posted my working [logging configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401935/2996101) for reference.