# Logging and email not working for Django for 500

Tags: python, django, email

I can't get logging to work in my Django web app.

My settings file looks like this:

```
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "paulhtremblay@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "password"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "paulhtremblay@gmail.com"
SERVER_EMAIL = 'smtp.gmail.com'

ADMINS = (
      ('Paul Tremblay', 'paulhtremblay@gmail.com'),
      )

 LOGGING = { 
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/var/log/django_logs/debug.log'
    },
    'mail_admins': {
     'level': 'ERROR',
       'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
               },
},  
'loggers': {
    'django': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': True,
    },
    'django.request': {
    'handlers': ['file'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': True,
    },
},  
 }
```

I have this in my views file:

```
 def five_hundred_test(request):
   raise ValueError("raising this on purpose for testing for 500")
   return render(request, 'my_test/basic_css.html')
```

When I point my browser to this function, I get a 500 Error (as expected), but nothing gets sent to my email, and nothing gets put in the log file. I am using Django 1.9, with python3, using Apache to run the server.

Comment: If you pasted the code properly, there a space too much before `LOGGING = {`. In any case you should always add the error traceback from the console.

Comment: I must not have pasted correctly. I see also that there is too much space before "LOGGING". However, the code does not raise any errors (so I can't include the trace). It just doesn't do what it is supposed to.

Comment: You have an error in the environment variables: [SERVER_EMAIL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#server-email) receives an email address. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

This is my working setup. I have not added a `console logger`, as I am using it only to production. The inspiration came from the relevant [Logging Examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#examples) of Django docs.

Here are my email and logging settings and here is a link to the relevant [django docs for the email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend):

```
from os.path import join

# Email Configuration ==========================================================
ADMINS = [('Me', 'my@email'), ]
MANAGERS = ADMINS
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'My Name To Display <my@email>'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'error_from@email'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.server'  # An IP may work better
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username_for_login'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password_for_login'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Logging Configuration ========================================================
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': join(HOME_DIR, 'my_logs', 'debug.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I have spotted two errors to your environment variables:

- The [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#server-email) setting must be be an email address.
- You are using `TLS` and therefore the correct port should be 587.

Moreover, you are trying to use Google as an SMTP server, but according to this [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367458/2996101) this service is no longer available from google and you have to search for another SMTP server.

I have also [assembled a post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419692/2996101) with a couple debugging techniques if you need to use.

Answer (score 9):

This can be done much simpler. If you want to log to both to email and Apache log files, you need to do the following in `settings.py`:

1. Configure email settings - **this assures that Django can send emails**

   ```
    SERVER_EMAIL = 'me@me.eu'

    EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.me.eu'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = SERVER_EMAIL
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
   ```
2. Set `DEBUG` to `False` - **this enables error email sending**

   ```
    DEBUG = False
   ```
3. Add error email receivers to `ADMINS` (you might want [MANAGERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-MANAGERS), too) - **this designates who receives the error emails**

   ```
    ADMINS = (
      ('Me', 'me@me.eu'),
    )

    MANAGERS = ADMINS
   ```
4. Finally, remove the default console filter that does not let messages through when debug mode is disabled - **this enables errors to end up in Apache error logs**

   ```
    from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

    # Assure that errors end up to Apache error logs via console output
    # when debug mode is disabled
    DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['console']['filters'] = []
   ```

   This has to be in `settings.py` as logging will be configured with `DEFAULT_LOGGING` immediately after settings have been imported.

In case you want to add support for **logging from your own code**, configure the root logger in `settings.py` as well:

```
# Enable logging to console from our modules by configuring the root logger
DEFAULT_LOGGING['loggers'][''] = {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'INFO',
    'propagate': True
}
```

Finally, you may want to turn on detailed logging:

```py
# Detailed log formatter
DEFAULT_LOGGING['formatters']['detailed'] = {
    'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {pathname}:{funcName}:{lineno} {message}',
    'style': '{',
}
DEFAULT_LOGGING['handlers']['console']['formatter'] = 'detailed'
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info('Logging works!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also check your email client rules on what to do with the emails once they arrive.

I had some rules in my e-mail client with errors and they were stopping my Django logging mails to enter/show up.