# django logging to a file does not work

Tags: django

The django settings.py has:

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/django.log',
            'maxBytes': 1000000,
            'backupCount': 10,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

and views.py has:

```
import logging
def some_view(request):
    logging.error('something')
```

I've also tried the following straight out of the [official django 1.8 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

I'm not getting this message in the log. However, if something throws and exception, that does show up in the django log file.
Also, if I set DEBUG=False in the settings and use a print statement instead of the logger, then the message shows up in the console.
At the bottom of the documentation, it says when DEBUG=True, all log levels should propagate, but they are not.
Any ideas how to make the logger messages appear in the log file at least with DEBUG=True?

Comment: It might be because of the typo **def some_view(erquest):**, you definitely meant **request**.

Comment: nah, just a typo when posting.

Comment: You may try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39401935/2996101) to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging
def some_view(request):
    logging.error('something')
```

The problem is when you call the logger on the views.
You should call the logger you created on the settings.
Like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'logfile': {
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/tmp/django.log',
            'maxBytes': 1000000,
            'backupCount': 10,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("django")

def some_view(request):

    logger.error('something')
```

Answer (score -2):

**Django Logging**

please go with following steps. 
add the configs on django project root settings.py file.

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            #'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'class': 'cloghandler.ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            #'level': 'DEBUG',
            #'filters': [],
            #'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
            #'filename': 'project/project/error.log',
            'filename' : 'None',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*10,
            'backupCount': 1000,
            #'when': 'midnight',
            #'interval': 1,
            #'utc': True,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['default'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```

In Views.py file

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def test_function(request):
    log.debug("Im Here to help you", exc_info=True)
```

Comment: This fails. several problems in the logger dict.