# Django SMTP settings

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, smtp, django-email

Maybe I wasn't clear enough about the problem, so I will try once more.
I need to use SMTP server to send large amount of emails with Django application. 
Settings that I used to establish connection are:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.premium-web-domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username@premium-web-domain.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
```

And I get error like this:
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:')

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: R u sure that your password is correct? Also no email port will have 25 as the port number

Comment: Pass and user are correct. Can you be more specific about the port.

Comment: the port should be `1025`, check it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django

Comment: It is very unlikely port 25 of the provider supports TLS. It is probably 587.

Comment: When I set false on ssl or tls, results were the same on port 25. Is port 587 only possible solution? When I used 587 port and gmail smtp everything worked just fine, but I cant sent many emails that way.