# Django: how to send email when the publish date is reached for a blog item

Tags: django

I have created a blog using Django

My blog model contains:

```
Title
Description
Image
Publish_date
Date_created
```

Now whenever i reach the publish_date, i want to send email or send some notification to an android app.

How to do that.

Comment: https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Django celery to check if the publish date reach or not. see Django celery
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html
 and if publish day found send email , see 
[How to send email via Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django)

Comment: any example on github.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function which gets executed everyday (maybe using cronjob). The function will filter by publish date. simply write a function to send a mail to each one.

That's the way it is done everywhere.