# Why after deploying django docker container, emails getting sending failed?

Tags: django, docker, smtp, dedicated-server, iaas

I was working on django and everthing was working fine on my local machine as well as on heroku.

But than i deodorize my django project and it was working fine locally till now. now i have depolyed this container on my dedicated server and than i came to know that my emails was failing after deployment.

Can anybody have idea why my dedicated server is not sending mails?

I am sending mails using smtp protocol.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're connecting to your local SMTP server to send out those emails.

The problem is that your Django is trying to use localhost:25 to send out the emails and in your docker there's no SMTP server. Docker has it's own network, and you can see what are the interfaces available by executing

```
ifconfig
```

To solve your issue, you should tell django to use your host SMTP server (and not localhost). Moreover you should tell your local SMTP server to accept emails coming from the docker network.