# Django Allauth Confirmation/verification email not sent after signing up

Tags: django-forms, django-authentication, django-allauth, django-custom-user

I am using a Custom user model and so far I have been able to hook it into the allauth package extending the "SignupForm".

Everything seems to work fine because I sign up and the information about the new account is in the DB (user table and account_emailaddress table) but the email is not sent.

here is what my signup form looks like

**forms.py**

```
class StudentSignUpForm(SignupForm): 

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(StudentSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = StudentProfile.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

**views.py**

```
def student_profile_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        user_form = StudentSignUpForm(request.POST, prefix='UF')

        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save(request)
            return redirect('/') 

    else: 
        user_form = StudentSignUpForm(prefix='UF')

    return render(request, 'registration/student-profile.html', {'user_form': user_form,})
```

This works for creating the Custom User as well as creating the user under All auth, the registered email address shows in the "/admin/" under accounts/emails_address but no confirmation emails are being sent to newly registered users.

How do I fix this?? Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

To send email you need to configure django email settings

Please follow [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/email/#quick-example) to send email and 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367014/how-to-send-email-via-django) to know about django settings for email

After saving user profile you call

```
class StudentSignUpForm(SignupForm): 
    ........
    student = StudentProfile.objects.create(user=user)
    send_mail(
        'Subject here',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@example.com',
        ['to@example.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Comment: Hi, I am using sendgrid as my email backend and it works well.  The funny thing is that if I use the inbuilt allauth signup form, I get an email confirmation mail but when I use my custom user form, no mails are sent... I need allauth to automatically send the email verification mail when user sign-up with my custom sign-up form.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
The problem was with the views, all I needed to do was to change into a class-based view and use the allauth signupview.

**In views.py**

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView


class student_profile_view(SignupView):

    # The referenced HTML content can be copied from the signup.html
    # in the django-allauth template folder

    template_name = 'registration/student-profile.html'

    # the previously created form class
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
```

then in my custom signup template, I just passed in "form" to render the registration form.

**in urls.py**

```
    path('register/student/', student_profile_view.as_view(), name='intern_register'),
```

Answer (score 0):

In `setting.py`, add:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION =”mandatory”
```